# Machine can't locate commands required to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I just tried to reboot my system and my computer keeps on throwing up a command prompt saying that it can't find certain commands like 'linux' that are necessary to boot my copy of Ubuntu. I run a Ubuntu/Windows 10 dual boot, I haven't booted windows in at least 6 months, and my partitions currently look like this:[screenshot of GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QphOw.png)

Recently I had problems updating my programs and killed all programs using '/var/lib/apt/lists/lock' but I don't think that should effect booting and immediately after I did that I preformed 'apt-get -f install' as well as 'apt-get update' and 'apt-get upgrade'. I'm currently running off of a live boot version designed to test out Ubuntu before installing.

Comment: @user245903 remember this is a Q&A site.  When someone asks a question or provides a comment you should edit your question with a summary of the question and with a response.  It is very difficult to read through a long list of comments.  Please can you summarise the various comments here in your question, raise a flag and then we can clean up by deleting all of these comments.  many thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69337/discussion-on-question-by-user245903-machine-cant-locate-commands-required-to-b).